# How to resolve an entry point path error?

Tags: xaml, path, windows-phone-8.1, manifest, entry-point

**Issue:**
I've moved the views in my application to a new folder named, 'Views'. But after moving the views I noticed I'm getting a navigation_failed event.

**Debugging Steps:**

In order to debug this I set a breakpoint on the exception message within the event. This then lead me to cause of the error, the compiler can't find the location of the moved view.

[image]

I tried to resolve this by updating the entry point and NavigationPage paths in the AppManifest.xml. To the new path of the view and the exception points that this path isn't correct.

Error:  `"No XAML was found at the location '/ParkingTagPicker.Views.MainPage'."`

I updated the entry point here in the manifest file:

```
EntryPoint="ParkingTagPicker.Views.MainPage"
```

**Question:**

Can anyone advise on the correct path string in this case?

My MainPage.xaml location is as follow in the solution:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="ParkingTagPicker.Views.MainPage"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                            Orientation="Portrait"
                            SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                            d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
                            shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
                            mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Answer (score 0):

When a page is in a subfolder, you must specify the full path for it, for example "Views/MainPage.xaml"

Same is valid when navigating between pages in the app, for example:

```
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/ChartComparePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```